# Difference between NSLog and LOG

Tags: ios, foundation

What differences does exist between that two commands.

```
NSLog(@"Hello World!!");
```

and

```
LOG(@"Hello World!!");
```

`NSLog` does display the message to the console, but `LOG` doesn't. So what is `LOG` for? Thanx in advance.

Comment: `LOG()` isn't a standard part of Cocoa -- where did you find it?

Comment: LOG() is not available in `COCOA` frame work. It was available in android framework. You are confused and mixing `android` and `COCOA`

Comment: @Josh Caswell: I am responsible of maintaining an existing project in my new company, i found that on their code.

Comment: It´s common to use NSLog through a macro so you can deactivate the log changing the macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to command + click the LOG() method to go to it's definition. Probably it is a custom log method in your project.

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply, this is its definition: `# define LOG(...) ;`. It's a constant, but, does this mean anything ?

Comment: This looks like the LOG(...) function is actually disabled by this statement. Do the LOG-statements in your code output anything?